# How to create a "title picture"

Tags: android, android-layout

For my app I want to have a design like this example I made in the top right corner at all times.
[image]

How would I create this? Would it have to be an image with textviews on it, or could I make one with programming?
All help is appreciated- Lijap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be implemented using TextView with a [9-patch background](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch)

Comment: How would I put both of those textviews inside, while keeping their placing the same? If you can help me with this I will absolutely accept your answer!

Comment: You can wrap two views by RelativeLayout or LinearLayout and assign a 9-patch background to the wrapper.  Sorry for the confusion, it does not have to be a TextView, it could be any view.